# Download dynamically created zip files in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, stream, playframework-2.0, zip

Hi i am trying to write a play framework service where i can download multiple files. I create zip of multiple file on the fly but i am not sure how to send it as a response in Play Framework i will show what i have done so far.

```
 public Result download() {

     String[] items = request().queryString().get("items[]");
        String toFilename = request().getQueryString("toFilename");

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(baos))) {
            for (String item : items) {
                Path path = Paths.get(REPOSITORY_BASE_PATH, item);
                if (Files.exists(path)) {
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(path.getFileName().toString());
                    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                    byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];
                    try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(path))) {
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        zos.closeEntry();
                    }
                }
            }

            response().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
            response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + MimeUtility.encodeWord(toFilename) + "\"");


//I am confused here how to output the response of zip file i have created
//I tried with the `baos` and with `zos` streams but not working

            return ok(baos.toByteArray());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("copy:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            return ok(error(e.getMessage()).toJSONString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

i tried sending response with `return ok(baos.toByteArray());` i was able to download file but when i open the downloaded file it give me error `An error occurred while loading the archive`.

Comment: What is not working? Have you inspected the response ? The ok method has a few options to response with files (File, InputStream), If you do not see the file opening a dialog to download the file you should add this to your response `application/x-download`

Comment: I mean i am able to download the file but when i open it my archive manager game me error of reading file

Comment: i tried sending response with  `return ok(baos.toByteArray());` and the file size seems ok but when i open the downloaded file it give me error `An error occured while loading the archive.`

Comment: Then the problem is not with play you may be doing something wrong when you are zipping the files.

Comment: I have the zip code above mentioned do you think is there anything wrong?

Comment: Have a look here to find some clues http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2015/08/21/packaging-a-zip-file-from-java-using-apache-commons-compress

Comment: i read it seems like its not helping in finding my answer still thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the zip file. After adding all entries, do: `zos.close()`

On a side note, I would recommend writing the zip file to disk rather than keeping it in a memory buffer. You could then use `return ok(File content, String filename)` to send its content to the client.

Comment: Great its working i forgot to close the stream. Thanks a lot you saved my headache :). I agree to not send content in memory and send them through file but it was actually requirement to not save in disk rather create directly on the fly :)

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this answer if someone wants to know what was the final code:

```
        String[] items = request().queryString().get("items[]");
        String toFilename = request().getQueryString("toFilename");

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(baos))) {
            for (String item : items) {
                Path path = Paths.get(REPOSITORY_BASE_PATH, item);
                if (Files.exists(path)) {
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(path.getFileName().toString());
                    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                    byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];
                    try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(path))) {
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }

                    } finally {
                        zos.closeEntry();
                    }
                }
            }

            zos.close(); //closing the Zip

            response().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
            response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + MimeUtility.encodeWord(toFilename) + "\"");
            return ok(baos.toByteArray());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("copy:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            return ok(error(e.getMessage()).toJSONString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help! There are two extra changes I made so it works for me in scala playframework 2.5.x

1. instead of `return ok(baos.toByteArray())` , 
   use `Ok.chunked(StreamConverters.fromInputStream(fileByteData))`
2. Instead of reading byte to byte the file,`FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)` can be very helpful here.

Attached is the complete version of my code.

```
import java.io.{BufferedOutputStream, ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream}
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipOutputStream}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{StreamConverters}
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

class HomeController extends Controller {
  def single() = Action {
                         Ok.sendFile(
                           content = new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\a.csv"),
                           fileName = _ => "a.csv"
                         )
                       }

  def zip() = Action {
                     Ok.chunked(StreamConverters.fromInputStream(fileByteData)).withHeaders(
                       CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/zip",
                       CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename = test.zip"
                     )
                   }

  def fileByteData(): ByteArrayInputStream = {
    val fileList = List(
      new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\a.csv"),
      new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\b.csv")
    )

    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(baos))

    try {
      fileList.map(file => {
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.toPath.getFileName.toString))
        zos.write(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))
        zos.closeEntry()
      })
    } finally {
      zos.close()
    }

    new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray)
  }
}
```